# Conditions for binary search to succeed in finding nearest neighbor on array of 3D points?

Tags: binary-search, nearest-neighbor

I have a ordered array of 3D points. The points represent a path in 3D space.

Given an arbitrary point I want to find the nearest point on the path.

If the path was relatively straight this would be trivial application of binary search, but since the path can have arbitrary curvature(looping back on itself) binary search may fail to find the nearest point.

My question is as follows:

What is the least strict constraint under which binary search will succeed to find the nearest point? Is it monotomic in each dimension? Is it related to the paths curvature? etc...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_database#Spatial_index ... I'm not sure a binary search can generally find the nearest point in a multidimensional set. Binary space partitioning should get you one of the closer points, but the cut might not get you *the* closest.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a little on whether your path is given or whether you are free to use any path you like.

Let's assume your path is given.
To answer your question: A simple binary search cannot be guaranteed to find the closest point. Imagine your path is a circle that is cut open at one place. The first and last point of your curve (the circle) will always be very close, but no binary search can fix that. As @Yann Vernier suggested, you can use spatial searches for that, search for "[nearest neighbor query](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search)", these can usually be done with spatial indexes such as [kd-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree), [quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) or [R-Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree). You can find Java implementations [here](https://github.com/tzaeschke/tinspin-indexes).

In case the path is not predefined, you can order the points with a [z-curve (morton order)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve) or [Hilbert curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve) (the curves being your path). This gives you a linear ordering which can searched with a binary search. This does not always give the closest point, but it is very fast, space efficient and will *often* give you the closest point. Hilbert curve is more likely to give you the closest point than z-curve, but it is harder to calculate.